# error in calculating standard deviation value

Tags: python, tensorflow, standard-deviation

I get two different values using tensorflow and numpy

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5] 
np.std(x)
```

gives `1.414`; whereas:

```
def std(x):
     _,var = tf.nn.moments(x,axis=[0])
     return var

x = tf.Variable([1,2,3,4,5],dtpye=tf.float32)

print(sess.run(tf.std(x))
```

gives `2.0`.

Did I declared `tensorflow` object correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [second central moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_%28mathematics%29#Significance_of_the_moments) of a sample is the variance (4+1+0+1+4)/5.=2.0 in your example. The std is its square root.